# Cannot convert date in string format to datetime object

Tags: python

I have a column date which I am trying to convert to date time, so I can extract month from those values. But not all values are getting converted properly and I cannot understand the reason for that.
Comparing 1st and 2nd to 3rd value in the sample.

The format for date is DD-MM-YYYY

This is what i have tried.

Here are the values I want to convert

```
05-02-2019
07-03-2019
18-03-2019
13-02-2019
05-03-2019
```

`sample['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample.date)`

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIpf7.png)

Comment: Please, add the dataframe sample in written format in stead of a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify `format`:

```
pd.to_datetime(sample['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.strptime()` method.
Eg :

```
date_dt1 = datetime.strptime(date_str1, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
```

% A - will give you weekday 
%B -  Month name 
%d -  Day of the month 
%Y -  will give you Year

Comment: it says:- "ValueError: time data '05-02-2019' does not match format '%B %d, %Y' "

Comment: The format was just an example, since he didn't know what format you were using. The point is that you have to consult the doc on `strptime` in order to determine the correct format for your data - in this case, `'%d-%m-%Y'` just like the format in the accepted answer.

Comment: @NickD I believe OP actually specified the format in the question, which was how I knew what format to use.

Comment: The timeline of edits suggests that the OP did that after this answer was posted. But the point is that the OP (every OP!) has to make some effort to try things out and at least understand the doc; otherwise, for every different time format there is going to be a different question.